# Would disabling object tracking in LINQ to SQL help me? And other speed improvements

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I know it seems trivial to test, but currently I'm unable to access my code to try this, plus I'd like to hear some other suggestions if anyone has them.

I have a LINQ-to-SQL query, that regularly returns 100000 records - it takes a good 20 seconds to retrieve these most of the time, which isn't acceptable. The data I retrieve is only ever going to be read - never updated or inserted into. I've read about the 'ObjectTrackingEnabled' property on the DataContext, and how it can help speed up queries - would this apply in my case? I imagine it's quite taxing to keep track of all 100000 objects.

Are there any other general LINQ-to-SQL improvements that I could try?

Many thanks

EDIT: Might be worth noting - my query has a 'select new' on it, but it does return a whole row from another table in a join

Comment: And how does it take to retrieve these records with the SqlDataAdapter / SqlDataReader? (I mean - what improvement could be expected at the C# level and what could you do to speed up the query at the SQL Server level)

Comment: Other than not using Linq-To-Sql?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. It seems relatively faster - just a couple of seconds, which would be ideal. I've spent a bit of time optimising the query for the best SQL.

Comment: The query you're running, does it return objects that are part of your data model?  If you were to return some sort of view object instead does that help (as it would not be tracked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to know what exact tricks will work without trying them, unfortunately. I'd say "sure, try turning everything fancy off in LINQ-to-SQL" - only you can measure how that impacts your system.

However; we too had some problems with materialization performance in LINQ-to-SQL, so for a lot of our performance-critical "read" queries we wrote and switched over to [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). This is a much simpler, but very optimized, API for executing queries into object models. It **does not** involve LINQ-to-SQL directly, so things like lazy-loading will not work, but it is really, really fast.

The general usage is like the `ExecuteQuery<T>(sql, args)` functionality of LINQ-to-SQL, except named-parameter TSQL syntax is used instead of the `{0}` / `{1}` string.Format syntax that LINQ-to-SQL uses, i.e.

```
// insanely simple example purely for illustration
int custId = ...
var orders = conn.Query<Order>(
       "select * from Order where CustomerId = @custId",
       new { custId });
```

If you are currently using a LINQ query, you can extract TSQL in a number of ways:

- SQL trace
- wire up `dbContext.Log` - perhaps (on a dev box) to `Console.Out`
- using [`mvc-mini-profiler`](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/), which can efficiently capture SQL operations even on a production box

We use this approach very successfully with our pre-existing LINQ-to-SQL types.